# How to determine the length of the wider base of a trapezoid from the shorter base length and only two angles?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How to determine the length of the wider base of a trapezoid from the shorter base length and only two angles are given?

Comment: Which two angles are given? The answer will depend on that.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I hope the pictures say it all. No matter which angles we are given, it seems that there are an infinitude of answers.